# Javascript: Listen for a callback to return

Tags: javascript, uwp, async-await

I am creating a UWP app in Javascript. And I need to translate some code from `C#` to javascript.
I am following this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-product-purchases) on how to add in-app purchases.

The need code in `C#` looks like this:

```
async void BuyFeature()
{
    if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["featureName"].IsActive)
    {
        try
        {
            // The customer doesn't own this feature, so
            // show the purchase dialog.
            await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("featureName", false);

            //Check the license state to determine if the in-app purchase was successful.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // The in-app purchase was not completed because
            // an error occurred.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The customer already owns this feature.
    }
}
```

As you can see in line 9 there is an wait function. How would I translate that into javascript?

So after calling in javascript ...

```
function abc() {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestProductPurchaseAsync("1", false);
    // something fancy here ... but that needs to wait
};
```

... I need to wait until it returns something and then proceed with the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: maybe this can help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: @GeomanYabes I've already looked at this (also the MDN Doc on the [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)), but using them gives me an error.

Comment: Neither of your recent questions is related to [tag:winapi] or [tag:c#]. Please remove those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description. I'd suppose your question here is how to use an asynchronous function in UWP with JavaScript.

> In many cases, calling an asynchronous function is almost as simple as calling a conventional function. The difference is that you use the [**then**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR229728) or the [**done**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701079) method to assign the handlers for results or errors and to start the operation.

So you can use [RequestProductPurchaseAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentAppSimulator_RequestProductPurchaseAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_) in JavaScript like the following. Please note [RequestProductPurchaseAsync(System.String,System.Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentAppSimulator_RequestProductPurchaseAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_) may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use [RequestProductPurchaseAsync(System.String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentAppSimulator_RequestProductPurchaseAsync_System_String_).

```
function abc() {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestProductPurchaseAsync("1").done(
        function (purchaseResults) {
            //TODO - purchaseResults is the return of requestProductPurchaseAsync method
        },
        function () {
            console.log("error: Unable to buy 1.");
        });
}
```

For more info, please see [Asynchronous patterns in UWP using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-patterns-in-uwp-using-javascript) and also for how to use [CurrentAppSimulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator), you may refer to [Trial app and in-app purchase sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is using a promise, something like this perhaps:

```
function productPurchaseAsyncCallExample(){
    return {response:'test response',errorCode:'ok/fail etc..'};
    // or whatever the response is...
}

var requestProductPurchaseAsync = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //We call resolve(...) when what we were doing async succeeded, and reject(...) when it failed.
    //In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code. 
    //In reality, you will probabally using something like XHR or an HTML5 API.
    //setTimeout(function(){
    //    resolve({success:'yes', bool:true}); //Yay! Everything went well!
    //}, 2250);
    resolve(productPurchaseAsyncCallExample());
});

function BuyFeature() {
    if (true){ // your if statement check
        requestProductPurchaseAsync.then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // do the rest
        });
    }
};


BuyFeature();
```

Comment: Where would I put `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestProductPurchaseAsync("1", false);` in that case?

Comment: `requestProductPurchaseAsync.then` runs the promise block so your http call (or whatever you are doing) would replace where the setTimeout is with the http call and params etc. Then when you get your response call the resolve() which signifies that the response is returned and allows the orignal .then call to continue.

Comment: Make sense? It's hard to speculate with unknowns as to what `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestPr‌​oductPurchaseAsync("‌​1", false);` does exactly.

Comment: I don't really know that either :) I've tried this: `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestProductPurchaseAsync("1", resolve({success:'yes', bool:true}));` but that immediately resolves

Comment: Try:
`resolve(productPurchaseAsyncCallExample());`

Are you sure you are calling something Async and not Sync?

Comment: Updated above code example for your latest query - but now it's just calling a function instead of something Async so the Promise isn't really needed - but it should give you an idea if your truly calling something Async. Is there not a common response expected from calling `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestPr‌​‌​oductPurchaseAsync‌​("‌​1", false);`?

Comment: I figured out a different solution to that problem. When calling `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.requestProductPurchaseAsync("1", false);` I just open a screen and the user needs in order to close that screen click a button which the initializes the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function abc() {
    var ans=testFn('a','b'); // let testFn is your function and assume it returns 'txt'
    while(ans!="txt"){}
    //do rest of code
    
}
```

Comment: What would I do if I don't know what it returns? I just know that it returns something.